# Htaccess raised bad flag delimiters error

Tags: php, macos, .htaccess, url-rewriting, clean-urls

I'm getting an error **RewriteRule: Bad flag delimiters**. When I access the page, the browser show 500 error. Can anyone point me in the right direction please. I am using xampp in MAC OS 10.9.2

Below is my htacess code. Its work perfectly in my hosting server which is linux but not in my localhost

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]s
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by removing the 's' in the last line

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```